# Passing values to applets

Tags: java, graphics, applet

I have a little problem with passing values from one class into another which extends the Applet class.
for eg. my From.java contains the following code:

```
public class From{
    public static Graphics g;
    String name = "Jack Black";
    To drawString = new To(g,name);
}
```

and my To.java contains this:

```
public class To extends Applet {
    To(Graphics g, String name){
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(name, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

I've made an constructor to pass the values, but i understand that paint method draws the graphics into Applet and thats why my code doesn't work. So, sadly, i cant make it working, I hope you guys can help me out here.

Comment: I think you should retrieve the Graphics from the Applet to draw anything, although you are probably better off putting a Canvas in your Applet and draw upon that.

Comment: *"..little problem with passing values from one class into another which extends the Applet class"*  Using that approach will be 'nothing but problems'.  Instead create a component to do the rendering, and add that to the applet.  If it needs parameters, define methods in the class to accept them.  Also 1) This is the 3rd millennium, use Swing ([JApplet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html)) rather than AWT. 2) Why an applet at all?  A [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) app. can be launched from a link and is a lot less difficult to deploy.

Comment: AFAICS this has nothing whatsoever to do with eclipse? Hence, I will remove the eclipse tag.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Hi :)

I watched your code and... You can simply modify your code in this direction as...

A)

```
public class From{

private String name;

public From(){}

public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
public String getName(){return this.name;}


}
```

B) Here is applet...

```
public class To extends Applet {

   Paint paint=new Paint();

   ...

   public void setFrom(From from)
{
    paint.drawString(from.getName());


}

}
```

C) And some simplification...

```
public class Paint extends JPanel
{

  private String name;

  public Paint (){}

  public void drawString(String name)
{

  this.name=name;
  this.repaint();
}

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(this.name, 20, 20);

}
}
```

That should help :)

Good luck